# Where to find the shared secret for iOS App Store receipt validation?

Tags: ios, receipt-validation, shared-secret

I am confused on where to find the shared secret needed to verify regular In-App purchases.

About one year ago I have created a server script which is call from my iOS app to verify the App Store receipt with Apples `.../verifyReceipt` endpoint.

This worked fine for the last year and now I would like to extend the script to do the same for a second app.

**The problem:** I don't remember where find the apps **shared secret** which has to be send with the receipt to Apple.

---

The secret for the first app ("MyApp") is stored within the script. But I was not able to re-find it within App Store Connect.

- Login to App Store Connect
- Go to "My Apps/MyApp/Features"
- Click on the link "App Specific Shared-Secret" above the "In-App Purchases" list.

This shows the information, that there is no app specific shared secret for MyApp but only a master shared secret. I can display the master shared secret but it is **not the same as the one stored in verification script**.

Additionally the info text says, that the app specific shared secret is used to verify auto-renewable subscriptions. Nothing about consumable or non-consumable IAPs.

Thus I assume that this is not the shared secret I am looking for. **But where else can I find the correct shared secret (the one that is already stored in my script?)**

Where can I find the secret for my new app?

Answer (score 21):

Just to update this again as of Jan/2023 - it can now be found in App Store Connect -> YOUR_APP -> App Information -> under the section titled "App-Specific Shared Secret" -> Manage

Comment: Took me forever to find. Thanks!

Comment: It's the valid solution now. Apple sucks! It changes its interface every single day. Updating (Dec. 15th).

Comment: @FellipeTavares i can't see an option for that. https://imgur.com/a/nLgrGY5

Comment: I am not able to see it either. I think they changed again...

Comment: Answer updated AGAIN to follow their new way of getting there.

Comment: As of today, I don't see it

Comment: @C.T.Bell I still see it in spot from my current answer. I can only think maybe you don't have proper permissions to update this? Just a guess.

Comment: My issue turned out to be server lag.

Comment: @Pramod Tapaniya , it's where Ronald informed in Jan 20th: App Store Connect -> YOUR_APP -> App Information -> under the section titled "App-Specific Shared Secret" -> Manage.

I just checked now!

Answer (score 18):

> Select your app in app-store connect -->  Select Features Tab on top
>   --> In-app purchase --> You will see the App specific shared secret at right corner.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the location I have already been looking at (please see my question). Problem is, that this link does not show an App-Specific Shared secret but only links to a Master Shared Secret which is NOT the same as the secret I am already using. Has the way the secrets are organized changed during the last month? Why is the old app specific secret still valid although it seems not to be listed in App Store Connect anymore?

Answer (score 13):

The 'App-Specific Shared Secret' is no longer available in the "Features" section.
It can now be found within App Store Connect -> YOUR_APP -> App Store -> In-App Purchases -> Manage.

Comment: This is true! I found it in the same line as the In-App Purchases

Answer (score 4):

Here is the **updated steps** to generate **App-Specific Shared Secret** for your application.

1. Login to [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/)
2. Go to **My Apps** & select your application
3. Select **App Information** option of General Section
4. Now you can see **App-Specific Shared Secret** section over there
5. Click on **Manage** button to generate secret key

Here is the screenshot for the same.

[image]